# What is the R function for selecting particular data from a large data set

Tags: r

```
Name  Age  Vaccination
A      12      yes
B      16      yes
C      12      no
D      19      no
F      21      yes
```

In this table, can someone tell me how should I write an R program to find out the mean of the age of people who have a vaccination status of YES?

Thank you

Comment: Try `mean(df$Age[df$Vaccination == 'yes'])
[1] 16.33333` OR `with(df, mean(Age[Vaccination == 'yes']))`

Comment: `aggregate(Age ~ Vaccination, df1, mean)`.